# Finding angles between two planes

Tags: vectors

> Find the angle between the planes:
>   $$\pi_1 : x − 2y + 2z = 1$$
>   and
>   $$\pi_2 : \begin{pmatrix}
>         x \\
>         y  \\
>         z  \\
>         \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
>         1 \\
>         1  \\
>         1  \\
>         \end{pmatrix} + \lambda\begin{pmatrix}
>         3 \\
>         0  \\
>         1  \\
>         \end{pmatrix} + \mu\begin{pmatrix}
>         0 \\
>         2  \\
>         -1  \\
>         \end{pmatrix} ,\ \lambda, \mu \in\mathbb{R}.$$

I'm not sure how to start with this problem and I really can't visualize the angle between the two planes.

So far I've tried visualizing the problem and finding out the vectors of the two planes, but haven't managed to get far.

Comment: The angle between two planes is defined as the angle of their normal vectors.  So the main task is to find a normal vector for the second plane.

Answer (score 1):

The normal vector to $\pi_1$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\2\end{pmatrix}$.

The normal vector to $\pi_2$ is
$\begin{pmatrix}3\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\3\\6\end{pmatrix}$.

The cosine of the angle between these two normals is their dot product divided by the product of their lengths.